# sized arrays as function parameter types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, struct, arrays

I am using templates for my struct like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T>
struct S
{
   T t;

   inline void Set(const T& val) { t = val; }
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

T can be an float, int, short or char[10], char[1] or char[2] (and preferably any length would be great).

While the above seems to work quite nicely for the integral types, I'm having difficulty implementing the char[n] portion in that:

1. I need to use strncpy or memcpy instead of the assignment operator
2. Using the above, the compiler complains about the signature (const char[2]& val) and my calling it via s.Set("T").
3. The interface between S with integral and character types has to be same as it's generic code that is calling them (and it doesn't care what type they are).

Comment: Why `char[]`s and not `std::string`s? You would not have these issues.

Comment: @Mat It's used in the context of packed structs to be put directly on the wire and std::string won't work for this purpose unfortunately.

Comment: You can still use a `std::string` for your `Set` method.

Comment: @Mat not sure I'm following.  Doesn't the parameter type in the Set method need to be the same as typename T?

Comment: @Mat: That won't take a short.  Christkirk: Yes it does.  See my answer, your code is fine.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I misread the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define template *specializations* for `T` in the case of `char[10]`, etc. Do any issues remain when you do that? But as Mat has already noted, using a string is an approach worth considering.

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T>
struct S
{
   T t;

   inline void Set(const T& val) { std::cout << "general\n"; }
};

template <int len>
struct S<char[len]>
{
   char t[len];

   inline void Set(const std::string& val) { std::cout << "specialization\n"; }
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {

    S<int> a;
    a.Set(10);

    S<char[20]> b;
    b.Set("turkey!");

    return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/X8YVuFja  output:

> general
>   specialization

Comment: I guess my issue is with C++ template syntax more than the concept.  Would you care to provide an example of such specialization?

Comment: @chriskirk: specialization effectively comes down to writing the class once for integral types, and once for char arrays.  That is avoidable, but can also make things easier.

Comment: @MooingDuck is it also possible to have std::string in the method signature for all specialization of type char[n]?  I think from the end-user perspective it would be a bit more convenient.

Comment: @chriskirk: Sure.  There's nothing that says that a specialization has to have _anything_ in common with the generic other than the fully qualified class name.

Comment: @MooingDuck Would you please care to provide an example of this?  I'm very intrigued indeed =)

Comment: @chriskirk: added demo to Dabbler's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a partial specialization might do the trick:

```
template <typename T> struct S
{
  T x;
  void set(const T & y) { x = y; }
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct S<T[N]>
{
  T x[N];
  void set(const T (&y)[N]) { std::copy(y, y + N, x); }
};
```

Usage:

```
S<char[10]> b;
char c[10] = "Hello";
b.set(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/03FSqZC6

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T>
struct S
{
   T t;

   inline void Set(const T& val) {}
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    typedef char (carray)[10];  //do you have a line like this?
    S<carray> lhs;
    carray rhs = "HELLO";
    lhs.Set(rhs);
    return 0;
}
```

Most likely your problem is caused by using the incorrect array type.  See my code for an example of a correct typedef.

## EDIT:

I just realized this becomes a pain to call `Set` if you already have a `std::string` or dynamic array of any sort.  Do the template specialization.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I wasn't using a typedef the way you outlined.

Comment: Are you sure this is doing what you think it does?

Comment: @KerrekSB: You make fewer mistakes than I do, but according to http://codepad.org/3DXoBLTf the sizes of `S`, `lhs`,`rhs`, and `val` are all 10.  What did I miss?

Comment: Well, your `Set` function is currently empty, so it's definitely not doing the right thing. The question is, how would the correct implementation look like?

Comment: That wasn't (technically) part of the qustion.  http://codepad.org/QNW6G8Qx  memcpy works, but only with POD types.  If he wants non-POD types, he'll have to specialize single vs. arrays.

Comment: @MooingDuck both implementations are good.  The only slight inconvenience I have now in both examples are that "..." implicitly assume an extra byte with \0 which goes beyond the bounds of the type.  I have to assign rhs like = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'} which is a bit annoying...

Comment: @chriskirk: No idea what you're referring to.  `carray rhs = "HELLO";` has no problems, it sets the other four `char`s to zero.  `char rhs[] = "HELLOKIRK";` likewise work fine.

Comment: @chriskirk: I just realized this is a pain to use if you have a string or dynamic array of any sort.  Go with the template specialization.

Comment: @MooingDuck the issue I have is that unfortunately "12345" puts an implicit '\0' at the end which results in errors like: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char [3]' to 'const char (&)[2]'

Comment: Could I instead make the method parameter const char* so I won't necessarily have to provide same-sized arguments?

Comment: @chriskirk: then you'd have to pass integers and such by pointer as well.   Go with template specialization.